# Lose focus when user clicks outside Node's bound in JavaFX

Tags: java, events, javafx, focus

I am new to JavaFX and I need help...

I have a TextField and I want this Node lose focus when the user clicks outside its bounds. 
Actually when the user clicks outside my TextField's bounds, the TextField keeps the focus.

If someone has an idea on how to perform this action... thanks in advance! It will help me a lot.

Thanks.

Hejk

Comment: You're far more likely to get answers if you include the actual code that's causing the problem - see [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this?  Open some simple applications on your own computer, like control panels or the Windows environment variables dialog.  Click in a text field, then click in the window's space between fields.  Notice the text field does not lose focus.  This is standard user interface behavior, and your application should behave the same way, since it's what users expect.  Surprising the user with unusual behavior, especially with no visual indication that it will happen, makes the user afraid to experiment with your application.

Comment: You can add a click handler on the parent that calls `requestFocus` on the parent. So the TextField lose its focus and the parent gets it.

Comment: @whrrgarbl, I do not have code for this. I really don't know how to perform this.

Comment: @VGR, it is the expected behavior... I know it is not user-friendly but I don't have the choice. ;)

Comment: @Hejk It's hard for anyone to provide code when you haven't provided the code you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick implementation of the behavior advised using the scene

```
scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
        if (!myFocusedNode.equals(event.getSource())) {
                   System.out.println("Clicked detected outside 'myFocusedNode' : {}", event.getSource());
                   myFocusedNode.getParent().requestFocus();
        }
});
```

It's a bit late response but I hope it will helps someone.